# 2nd order linear ODE with constant driving term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this DE$$y''+ay'=c $$
I tried with undetermined coefficient method, but the ansatz of particular solution being a zeroth order polynomial obviously doesn't work(LHS is 0). How do I solve this problem? do I have to use variation of parameters or the ansatz is not right?

Comment: You can view it as a DE in $y'$ and solve that using the integrating factor method. 

Otherwise your particular integral here will be $y = \frac{c}{a}x$ for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating factor method works fine
$$y''+ay'=c$$
use $\mu(x)=e^{ax}$ as integrating factor
$$(y'e^{ax})'=ce^{ax}$$
Integrate 
$$y'e^{ax}=c\int e^{ax}dx =\frac ca {e^{ax}}+K$$
$$y'=e^{-ax} \left (\frac ca {e^{ax}}+K \right )$$
$$y'=\frac ca+Ke^{-ax}$$
Integrate again
$$\boxed{y=\frac cax+K_1e^{-ax}+K_2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Integrating once

$$
y'+ay=c x+C_1
$$

and now the first order linear differential equation with solution

$$
y = \frac{c (a x-1)+a C_1}{a^2}+C_2 e^{-a x}
$$